# Join sql results

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please, help me with join results of commands (MS SQL):

```
SELECT name,value FROM table1  WHERE idfoo1 IN(SELECT _id FROM table3 where id = 1);
SELECT value FROM table2  WHERE idfoo2 IN(SELECT _id_2 FROM table3 where id = 1) AND name='fooname';
```

And I get:

```
name  value 
John  2     
Bill  32    
Alex  11   

value
434
234
144
```

But I need join results.

```
name  value value
John  2     434
Bill  32    234
Alex  11    144
```

So, id == id, _id != _id_2,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this query:

```
SELECT t1.name,
       t1.value,
       t2.value
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.idfoo1 = t3._id
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.idfoo2 = t3._id_2
WHERE t3.id=1 AND t2.name = 'fooname'
```

Comment: this should be removed "WHERE t3.id = 1 and t2.name = 'fooname'"

Comment: I would have actually preferred the filters as filters in the where clause, since they're technically not join criteria.

Comment: @AaronBertrand indeed, so do I :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Select  a.name,a.value,c.value FROM table1  as a inner join table3 as b
on a.idfoo1=b.id and b.id=1 inner join table3 as c
on c.idfoo2=b._id_2 and b.id=1 and c.name='fooname'
```

Answer (score -2):

i guess this is what you need-

```
SELECT t1.name, t1.value, t2.value
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2, table3 t3 
WHERE 
   t1.idfoo1 = t3._id
   AND t2.idfoo2 = t3._id_2
   AND t3.id = 1
   AND t2.name='fooname';
```

Comment: Who's up-voting this? It doesn't even parse and it is using old-style joins which are far from best practice.

Comment: I don't agree with your `old-style joins` view of thinking. There are already 100's of discussion floating around on this with no solid conclusion. The only point which justify inner join is that it separates the 'join criteria' from the 'where clauses'. And i do agree inner joins are more readable in case of very complex queries. Other than that there is no performance difference in two, and I personally prefer using implicit joins in simple joins to keep the query simple. It depends on personal preferences as which one is to use.

Comment: The danger with old-style joins is that it much easier to inadvertently derive a Cartesian product, precisely because the join criteria and filter criteria are munged together. And if you have to add a left join to the query, now you have to deal with a query that has mixed styles. Why not use the more modern style all the time? Is saving 14 characters really making your query that much simpler? Have a read of [this blog post](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins).

Comment: Nice article! I do agree with your concern of cross joins. But using inner joins just because some day we might have to change it to outer joins..well it doesn't justify. Inner joins make query readable but only when you are playing with complex ones..otherwise I will keep it to individual preference...and yes, been a lazy developer as I am, putting 14 more characters without any performance benefit is more for me....besides it not 14 ..its 22 characters! :)

Comment: It's not just about whether the query will change later, it's also about consistency. If you have two completely separate queries, one has two inner joins, the other has two inner joins and a left join, does laziness really justify using one style in one case and a different style in the other case? Why? Also don't forget to add the  extra character you need to write `AND` instead of `ON` (and the initial `WHERE`, too, if there are no non-join-related filters).